# one controller for three pages

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I have one controller ADD. I want this controller to manipulate three pages: `add_customer` page, `add_project` page and `add_post_page`.In this case add_project page works perfectly. But `add_customer` and `add_post` pages have errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).

I think the problem is in my coditions here:

```
public function index(){
    if($this->uri->segment(3)=='add_customer'){
        $this->add_customer(); 
    }
    else if($this->uri->segment(3)=='add_post'){
        $this->add_post(); 
    }
    else{
        $this->add_project(); 
    }
}
```

This is my full controller:

```
class ADD  extends MX_Controller {

public $mname, $tag, $tpl;

function __construct()
{
    $this->mname=strtolower(get_class());             
    $this->tag=strtoupper($this->mname); 
} 


public function index(){

    if($this->uri->segment(3)=='add_customer'){
        $this->add_customer(); 
    }

    else if($this->uri->segment(3)=='add_post'){
        $this->add_post(); 
    }

    else{
        $this->add_project(); 
    }

}

public function add_project()
{ 
    include APPPATH."language/".LANG.".php";

    $this->load->model($this->mname.'/add_project_model');
    $model='add_project_model';
    $this->$model->index($this->mname);

    $a['IsEnabled']=$LANGUAGE['IsEnabled']; 
    $a['Submit']=$LANGUAGE['Submit'];
    $a['Cancel']=$LANGUAGE['Cancel'];
    $a['Reset']=$LANGUAGE['Reset'];
    $a['Name']=$LANGUAGE['Name'];
    $a['SelectCustomer']=$LANGUAGE['SelectCustomer'];
    $a['Project Name']=$LANGUAGE['ProjectName'];
    $a['Manager']=$LANGUAGE['Manager'];
    $a['Customer']=$LANGUAGE['Customer'];

    $userGROUP = $this->session->userdata('_userGROUP');
    if ($userGROUP=='Administrator')
        $a['AddManager']='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="AddNewManager()">+</button>';
    else
        $a['AddManager']='';

    $this->tp->assign($a);
    $this->tp->parse('CONTENT', $this->mname.'/add_project.tpl');
}

public function add_customer()
{   
    include APPPATH."language/".LANG.".php";

    $userGROUP = $this->session->userdata('_userGROUP');

    if($userGROUP!=='Administrator')
    {
        show_404('page');
        exit; 
    }

    $this->load->model($this->mname.'/add_customer_model');
    $model='add_customer_model';
    $this->$model->index($this->mname);


    $a['IsEnabled']=$LANGUAGE['IsEnabled']; 
    $a['Submit']=$LANGUAGE['Submit'];
    $a['Cancel']=$LANGUAGE['Cancel'];
    $a['Reset']=$LANGUAGE['Reset'];
    $a['Name']=$LANGUAGE['Name'];
    $a['Project Name']=$LANGUAGE['CustomerName'];
    $a['Customer Name']=$LANGUAGE['Customer Name'];

    $this->tp->assign($a);
    $this->tp->parse('CONTENT', $this->mname.'/add_customer.tpl');
}


public function add_post()
{ 
    include APPPATH."language/".LANG.".php";

    $userGROUP = $this->session->userdata('_userGROUP');

    if($userGROUP=='Engineer')
    {
        show_404('page');
        exit; 
    }

    $this->load->model($this->mname.'/add_post_model');
    $model='add_post_model';
    $this->$model->index($this->mname);


    $a['IsEnabled']=$LANGUAGE['IsEnabled']; 
    $a['Submit']=$LANGUAGE['Submit'];
    $a['Cancel']=$LANGUAGE['Cancel'];
    $a['Reset']=$LANGUAGE['Reset'];
    $a['Activity Name']=$LANGUAGE['Activity Name'];
    $a['SalaryHour']=$LANGUAGE['SalaryHour'];

    $this->tp->assign($a);
    $this->tp->parse('CONTENT', $this->mname.'/add_post.tpl');
}

}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Remove `if elseif else` block from `index()` method. Leave just `$this->add_project()` line.

Comment: But how will add_post and add_customer pages work from this controller?

Comment: When you enter in browser something like: `http://project.dev/add/add_project` it never reaches `index()` method. If you enter index method it never reaches other method and consequently never appear in URL/uri segment.

Answer (score 0):

Just Give it a Try, Hope it works :

```
public function index(){
    if($this->uri->segment(3)=='add_customer'){
        redirect(base_url().'/Add/add_customer');
        //$this->add_customer(); 
    }
    else if($this->uri->segment(3)=='add_post'){
        redirect(base_url().'/Add/add_post');
        //$this->add_post(); 
    }
    else{
        redirect(base_url().'/Add/add_project');
        //$this->add_project(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u!! but unfortunately it doesn't work :( The 404 error is:The page you requested was not found.

Comment: What is the Link that is generated by calling the "Redirect" function ?

Comment: @Ksenia I have Made changes in my answer,please try hope that works.

Comment: now the link is: http://localhost/codeigniter2//Add/add_project -  it doesn't see the language between codeigniter2 and Add.
I'm sorry to bother you!

Comment: No, cause language must be between them for sure

Comment: Try this :            redirect(base_url().LANGUAGE.'/Add/add_customer'); Where LANGUAGE is a Constant or any variable in which Language is used.

Comment: now it says: This page isn’t working. localhost redirected you too many times. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your index function is never reached

This would reach it : `http://project.dev/add`

By default the following urls hit the appropriate function.

`http://project.dev/add/add_customer` hit public function add_customer()

`http://project.dev/add/add_post` hit public function add_post()

If you are getting errors check out the various error in the specific function and make sure you have error reporting turned on